# Hippo CMS for java Login Logout

Tags: java, content-management-system

I am new to Hippo CMS. After configuring Hippo CMS I tried to run it in my localhost using this url(http://localhost:9080/cms/console/?0). So here I want to ask what will be username and password to login to console or how can change or assign login credentials,Please help.!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use username: admin and password: admin to login as an admin
In the cms you can also login as an author by using username: author and password: author or you can login as an editor using username: editor and password: editor

I would recommend to follow the developer trails (http://www.onehippo.org/trails/getting-started/hippo-essentials-getting-started.html) a lot gets explained there!